# Error when getting my Signed APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I need to get my .apk in android studio so that I can package it, But I had an error when I Generate Signed APK. The first error is:

```
Error:(50) Error: The <uses-permission> element must be a direct child of the <manifest> root element [WrongManifestParent]
```

and when I double click that error, it leads to this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

The next error is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
```

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

What to do? Are there other ways in getting my .APK?

Comment: and when I double click that error .. it leads to this line:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

Comment: The next error is: Lint foind fatal errors while assembling a release target. To proceed, ...............

Comment: "The element must be a direct child of the root element [WrongManifestParent]"... can we see the manifest?

Comment: How can I show the manifest ?  It exceeds the characters here .. Is it the whole .xml ? 

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anadanielladeleon.mg">
......
.....
.....

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
        <receiver android:name =".Notification_receiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: edit the question